# Using a TestCase subclass in another unit test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, subclass, python-unittest

Here's an example:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class DogTest(TestCase):

    def create_dog(self, weight):

        dog = {'weight': weight}

        return dog


class DogPawTest(TestCase):

    def test_dog_paw(self):

        dog_test = DogTest()
        dog = dog_test.create_dog(weight=10)
        self.assertEqual(dog['weight'], 10)
```

It throws

```
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest_case_import.DogTest'>: runTest
```

Test cases should be independent. Also, `create_dog` can and should be outside of the test class. Changing the definition to `DogTest(object)` solves the riddle. But I have a case where it's not an option.

How can I use the methods of another `TestCase`-based class in `test_dog_paw`?

Comment: you can use ```DogPawTest(DogTest)``` in DogPawTest.  and use ```self.create_dog(weight=10```

Comment: @ManojJadhav Alas, in my case I have to import multiple TestCase classes  within a single class. Mixins may help, but it'd involve much refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

With the example you have provided I don't see any need for inheritance. You could just as easily do something like:

```
from unittest import TestCase

def create_dog(weight):
    return {'weight': weight}

class DogTest(TestCase):
    def test_dogs(self):
        heavy_dog = create_dog(25)
        ...

class DogPawTest(TestCase):
    def test_dog_paw(self):
        dog = create_dog(weight=10)
        self.assertEqual(dog['weight'], 10)
```

It could also be worth having a look at something like PyTest's [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html). That might change this code to be something like:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def dog():
    """Just your regular average dog"""
    return {'weight': 15}

@pytest.fixture
def heavy_dog():
    return {'weight': 30}

@pytest.fixture
def light_dog():
    return {'weight': 10}

class DogTest(TestCase):
    def test_dogs(self, heavy_dog):
        ...

class DogPawTest(TestCase):
    def test_dog_paw(self, dog):
        self.assertEqual(dog['weight'], 10)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the code that forces me to inherit, so I was looking for short ways to create an instance of an established test case.

Comment: Well, my answer is not really applicable then I guess.